# Incompatibility using std::string::assign from boost::array Vs std::array

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, visual-c++-2019

Some legacy code looks like:

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>

boost::array<wchar_t, 1000> data;

void func(std::wstring &str)
{
 str.assign(data.begin());
}
```

I am updating code to use `std` equivalents to `boost` as we update to C++17, and I thought `array` was a direct replacement, but when I try this I get a compile error:

```
#include <array>

std::array<wchar_t, 1000> data;

void func(std::wstring &str)
{
 str.assign(data.begin());
}
```

> error C2664:
> 'std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>
> &std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>::assign(std::initializer_list<_Elem>)':
> cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,2001>' to
> 'std::initializer_list<_Elem>'
> with
> [
> _Elem=wchar_t
> ]
> and
> [
> _Ty=wchar_t
> ]
> and
> [
> _Elem=wchar_t
> ]

We use this pattern in quite a lot of places in our codebase, is there a trivial fix? What specifically is the difference between `boost::array` and `std::array` which causes this, and does this mean it cannot be considered a drop-in replacement?

(I didn't write this code. And I don't know why we aren't just using `wchar_t[]`; maybe the author just liked the 'new' features in boost.)

Comment: Does `str.assign(data.begin(), data.end())` work? Otherwise instead of passing an iterator you might just directly want the array/pointer like `str.assign(data.data())` if you are sure that `data` will be null terminated

Comment: More than likely `boost::array::begin` returns a pointer. It's a valid implementation for an iterator. Frankly, it looks like the author was abusing an implementation detail.

Comment: @CoryKramer it _compiles_ being sure it _works_ might take a little longer ;) This does look much nicer, I wonder how boost's iterator differs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::array<wchar_t, N>::iterator` is defined as an `wchar_t *`

`std::array<wchar_t, N>::iterator` is not required to be a `wchar_t *`.

That's why your code fails to compile.  It assumes that the iterators are pointers.

Besides that, the code you have is problematic because `str.assign(_pointer_)` assumes that the pointer points to a null-terminated string.

However, the good news is that `str.assign(data.begin(), data.end())` will work for `boost::array` and `std::array` both.

However, if you have a NUL in the middle of the array, then you'll get different behavior than you did before. This will give you the same behavior as before:

`str.assign(data.begin(), std::find(data.begin(), data.end(), wchar_t(0)))`

[Later: Well, except in the case where `data` did not contain a NUL. In that case, you had undefined behavior before, but now you get all the elements in the array (and only those). ]

Comment: The usage seems purely to have been a char-buffer to receive the result from an ODBC call, traditionally you see `WCHAR[MAX_LEN]` so I get the impression someone had read about boost arrays 10+ years ago and wanted to use them.